# Node http proxy with proxytable and websockets

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, node-http-proxy

I'm trying to get websockets to also work with `node-http-proxy`. The difference is i'm using a proxytable:

```
var options = {
router: {
    'a.websterten.com': '127.0.0.1:150',
    'b.websterten.com' : '127.0.0.1:151',
}
};

var server = httpProxy.createServer(options);
```

I tried:

```
server.on('upgrade', function (req, socket, head) {
    server.proxy.proxyWebSocketRequest(req, socket, head);
});
```

But it doesn't seem to work. A quick check to see whether websockets work shows I get `Unexpected response code: 400` from Chrome (works fine if I go directly)

Also doing a couple of checks `server.on('upgrade',..` doesn't fire on a websocket request

How can I get my proxy server to route websockets correctly?

I've also tried this on node 0.8.23 as well as node 0.10.x (the later versions of node have a memory leak issue, but it wont work on 0.8.23 either)

Answer (score 2):

When you use `httpProxy.createServer()`, it's not necessary to handle the `upgrade` event because http-proxy handles it automatically.  Thus, your `server.on('upgrade', ...)` never fires because http-proxy is already handling it internally.

The only time you need to do `server.on('upgrade')` is when you pass middleware functions to `httpProxy.createServer` or if you've manually created the server with `http.createServer()`.

In other words, websockets should "just work" through the proxy in your configuration.

---

**However,** WebSocket support in http-proxy is [currently **broken** on node v0.10.x](https://github.com/nodejitsu/node-http-proxy/issues/387) because of streams2 (the stream APIs in node core [were completely rewritten in 0.10](http://blog.nodejs.org/2012/12/20/streams2/)).  **Also**, the most recent release of http-proxy (0.10.2) is broken in node v0.8 because of a [botched fix](https://github.com/nodejitsu/node-http-proxy/pull/402) for the streams2 issue.

So you have two options:

1. Wait for http-proxy to rewrite its internals to cope with streams2.
2. Downgrade to node v0.8.23 and http-proxy 0.10.1.  (At least until #1 happens.)

(You can install old versions of npm modules by running `npm install http-proxy@0.10.1`.)

Comment: I have tried this, with and without the upgrade nothing happens, I dont even get errors either & eventually it crashes. I'm using the proxy table example and just modified the hostnames to other ones, no other edits

Comment: @Akshat: Further research reveals it's actually an incompatibility with node 0.10.  See update.

Comment: I see, I also had the issue with 0.8.2 with the recent update. Is there no workaround for this?

Comment: @Akshat: There was a [patch](https://github.com/nodejitsu/node-http-proxy/pull/402) in the most recent release of http-proxy intended to fix the issue (at least temporarily), but it is not a complete fix; that's why socket.io doesn't work and why that version doesn't seem to work in node v0.8.   Try installing the previous release of http-proxy, 0.10.1.

Comment: I tried downgrading to node 0.8.23 but the websocket still wont connect (I get a 400 error in chrome), the memory leak errors do however disappear.