# socket.io example sometimes not connecting client side when using a reverse proxy

Tags: node.js, socket.io, node-http-proxy

Using node-http-proxy, I've set up a reverse proxy for routing requests:

```
var httpProxy = require('http-proxy');
var server = httpProxy.createServer({
    hostnameOnly: true,
    router: {
        'www.example.com': 'localhost:3002'
    }
}).listen(80);
```

Now, when I run the first example on http://socket.io/#how-to-use, the socket is sometimes not connecting with the client. I created two files to test this: server.js and index.html. To start the node application, i run server.js.

**server.js:**

```
var app = require('http').createServer(handler)
    , io = require('socket.io').listen(app)
    , fs = require('fs')

app.listen(3002);

function handler (req, res) {
    fs.readFile(__dirname + '/index.html',
    function (err, data) {
        if (err) {
            res.writeHead(500);
            return res.end('Error loading index.html');
        }

        res.writeHead(200);
        res.end(data);
    });
}

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    console.log("Socket connected");
});
```

**index.html:**

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
    var socket = io.connect();
    setInterval(function() {
        console.log(socket.socket.connected);
    }, 1000)
</script>
```

When the client does not connect, after the socket connects with the server, I repeatedly get the following output with intervals of +/- 10 seconds:

```
debug - setting request GET /socket.io/1/xhr-polling/Cqcw5xUjQ-B-Hw3FGF7Y?t=1385128607702
debug - setting poll timeout
debug - discarding transport
debug - cleared heartbeat interval for client Cqcw5xUjQ-B-Hw3FGF7Y
```

Now, when I refresh the browser a few times, the socket always connects with the server (that is, it always logs *"Socket connected"*), but sometimes it does not connect client side: `console.log(socket.socket.connected)` sometimes repeatedly prints *"false"* after refreshing index.html, and after another page refresh, it may repeatedly print *"true"* or *"false"* again if the socket did not or did connect with the client.

The example does work client-side when I do not use the reverse proxy, so when I run server.js on port 80 on www.example.com. It would be great if someone could point me out what could be the cause of this problem. I am using node.js v0.8.23, socket.io version 0.9.14 and node-http-proxy version 0.10.1.

**UPDATE**

Probably, I am actually using node v0.10.21. I thought I was using v0.8.23 by switching the node version using [nvm](https://github.com/creationix/nvm), but for some reason it keeps switching back to v0.10. It is a [known issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16503349/node-http-proxy-with-proxytable-and-websockets) that http-proxy does not support web sockets for node versions later than 0.8, so that may be the cause. I am using robertklep's solution until I find something better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really was the node version I was using. Node-http-proxy does not work for node version >0.8 (see [Node http proxy with proxytable and websockets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16503349/node-http-proxy-with-proxytable-and-websockets)). I thought I was using v0.8.23 but I was actually using v0.10.21. By using [n](https://github.com/visionmedia/n), I could get node working for v0.8.23 for sure, and now it seems to work. I highly recommend n for resetting the node version.

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue might be that `socket.io` is initially trying to use WebSockets as a transport medium and when that doesn't work (I don't know if `node-http-proxy` can proxy WS connections), it falls back to a transport that does work (`xhr-polling`) but the client and/or server gets confused in the process.

Try disabling the `websocket` and `flashsocket` transports to see if that makes it more reliable:

```
io.set('transports', [ 'xhr-polling', 'jsonp-polling', 'htmlfile' ]);
```

([more info](https://github.com/LearnBoost/Socket.IO/wiki/Configuring-Socket.IO#recommended-production-settings))

Comment: That indeed makes the socket work consistently, however, I get the following messages every +/- 10 seconds (it still works though):    debug - clearing poll timeout
   debug - xhr-polling writing 8::
   debug - set close timeout for client U-xdq5jRtzoK6f9qXi4V
   debug - xhr-polling closed due to exceeded duration
   debug - setting request GET /socket.io/1/xhr-polling/U-xdq5jRtzoK6f9qXi4V?t=1385133212017
   debug - setting poll timeout
   debug - discarding transport
   debug - cleared close timeout for client U-xdq5jRtzoK6f9qXi4V

Comment: @GuidoPassage perhaps [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18064892/893780) might provide some insight (although it's not entirely clear to me what's it about :)

Comment: That is nice to know. I will use your solution until I find something better. My site is not visited frequently yet, so the performance difference should not matter too much. Thank you for your suggestions.